# How to open the app when user tap on the firebase dynamic link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a dynamic link: `https://test.app.goo.gl/name` and I've added this to associated domains: test.app.goo.gl. In the info in URLTypes section, I've added URL Scheme: `com.project.lad` When I press on the dynamic link, I can see window with "open in app button", but when tap on this button, opens the website not the app.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the document provided to receive a dynamic link that will open in your app - https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive

if you followed documents properly then try to add the following code in SceneDelegate.swift file. it might help.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
 if let incomigURL = userActivity.webpageURL{
            _ = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomigURL) { (dynamiclink, error) in
                if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink, let _ = dynamiclink.url {
                    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamiclink)
                } else {
                    print("dynamiclink = nil")
                }
            }
}



 func handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: DynamicLink){
        print("Your dynamic link parameter is = \(String(describing: dynamicLink.url))")
       
        let link = dynamicLink.url?.absoluteString
       //your code
}
```

Comment: I've already done everything like in this documentation, but it's not working yet.

Comment: add above code in sceneDelegate you might get a response of dynamic link in this file.

Comment: But it's for SwiftUI, I don't have scene delegate